# Quitting processes in PySide Dialog Window

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt, pyside

Ok, let's say that I have a theoretical application written in PySide and I want to integrate video tutorials on how to use certain functions and tools all within a dialog window that loads an instance of webview.

E.g.:

```
class TutorialWindow(QtGui.QDialog)
 (Some code)
....
....
(Some code)
video = QtWebKit.QWebView()
video.load(QUrl(youtube.com/video)
```

Well, the issue that I'm running into is that the video continues to play even after the dialog window has been closed. I know this is because the audio continues to play until I close the parent application.

I'm looking into the documentation for the dialog window close event but, I feel I'm missing something.

*I apologize for any incoherent-ness, I have been machining some components on a CNC for the past 8 hours at 4:00AM.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. You might also want to try and reproduce the problem with PyQt4.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I can actually do one better if you'd like; here is the link to the whole application on GitHub: git@github.com:bleucanary/SparkControl0.2.0.git

Comment: While I appreciate the link, that is not considered better than a minimal working example included with the question. Creating the minimal example saves the time of someone answering the question and more importantly, helps you isolate whether the issue is with the library or your implementation of it. You will probably find your question is put "on hold" if you don't provide the MCVE.